# How to Navigate to User's Specific Path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

[I have a Vitals Page for each user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvufT.jpg)

This is populated in the above vitals path from various models I have in my app.
User1 books an appointment with User2 (Doctor) ....(I don't have 2 user types)
[User 2's View of Appointment booked by User1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvaYT.jpg)

When User2 click's on the Vitals and Reports in the Your Patients Section....
I am still seeing the Vitals and Reports of User2 but I want to see User 1's Vital and Reports Pages.

How do I do it??

This is my Reports Controller:

```
            class ReportsController < ApplicationController
              before_action :set_report, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
              before_action :authenticate_user!

              # GET /reports
              # GET /reports.json
              def index
                @reports = current_user.reports
              end

              # GET /reports/1
              # GET /reports/1.json
              def show

              end

              # GET /reports/new
              def new
                @report = current_user.reports.build
              end

              # GET /reports/1/edit
              def edit
              end

              # POST /reports
              # POST /reports.json
              def create
                @report = current_user.reports.build(report_params)

                respond_to do |format|
                  if @report.save
                    format.html { redirect_to @report, notice: 'Report was successfully created.' }
                    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @report }
                  else
                    format.html { render :new }
                    format.json { render json: @report.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
                  end
                end
              end

              # PATCH/PUT /reports/1
              # PATCH/PUT /reports/1.json
              def update
                respond_to do |format|
                  if @report.update(report_params)
                    format.html { redirect_to @report, notice: 'Report was successfully updated.' }
                    format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @report }
                  else
                    format.html { render :edit }
                    format.json { render json: @report.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
                  end
                end
              end

              # DELETE /reports/1
              # DELETE /reports/1.json
              def destroy
                if current_user.id == @report.user.id
                  @report.destroy
                respond_to do |format|
                  format.html { redirect_to reports_url, notice: 'Report was successfully destroyed.' }
                  format.json { head :no_content }
                end
              else
                redirect_to root_path, notice: "You don't have permission."
                end
              end

              private
                # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
                def set_report
                  @report = Report.find(params[:id])
                end

                # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
                def report_params
                  params.require(:report).permit(:name, :attachment)
                end
            end
```

And this is my Appointments Controller:

```
            class AppointmentsController < ApplicationController
               before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:notify]



                def preload
                    practice = Practice.find(params[:practice_id])
                    today = Date.today
                    appointments = practice.appointments.where("date >= ?", today)

                    render json: appointments
                end

                def create
                    @appointment = current_user.appointments.create(appointment_params)

                    if @appointment
                        # send request to PayPal
                        values = {
                            business: 'abc@gmail.com',
                            cmd: '_xclick',
                            upload: 1,
                            notify_url: 'url.com',
                            amount: @appointment.price,
                            item_name: @appointment.practice.speciality,
                            item_number: @appointment.id,
                            quantity: '1',
                            return: 'url.com/your_trips'
                        }

                        redirect_to "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?" + values.to_query
                    else
                        redirect_to @appointment.practice, alert: "Oops, something went wrong..."
                    end 
                end


                protect_from_forgery except: [:notify]
                def notify
                    params.permit!
                    status = params[:payment_status]

                    appointment = Appointment.find(params[:item_number])

                    if status == "Completed"
                        appointment.update_attributes status: true
                    else
                        appointment.destroy
                    end

                    render nothing: true
                end

                protect_from_forgery except: [:your_trips]
                def your_trips
                    @trips = current_user.appointments.where("status = ?", true)
                end

                def your_appointments
                    @practices = current_user.practices
                end

                def check_date_time
                    if params[:time].blank? || params[:date].blank?
                        render json: {status: true}
                    else
                        arr = []
                        arr1 = []
                        Appointment.where(practice_id: params[:practice_id]).map{|a| arr << "#{a.date} #{a.time.strftime("%T") }" unless a.time.nil? }
                        arr.map{|a| arr1 << DateTime.parse(a).to_i }
                        d = DateTime.parse("#{params[:date]} #{params[:time]}").to_i
                        if arr1.include?(d)
                            render json: {status: false}
                        else
                            render json: {status: true}
                        end
                    end
                end

                private


                    def appointment_params
                        params.require(:appointment).permit(:date, :hour, :price, :reason, :practice_id, :time)
                    end
            end
```

Comment: You have a pretty serious bug in `AppointmentsController#create`. `#create` - "Creates an object (or multiple objects) and saves it to the database, if validations pass. The resulting object is returned whether the object was saved successfully to the database or not". So `if @appointment` is always true. You need to check `if @appointment.persisted?`.

Comment: Thanks! ....changed it!